# How to mark High of today if it has a particular decimal say ".55" at end for a 5m interval chart in Tradingview using Pine script

Tags: plot, conditional-statements

What I want to do is to mark the candle in 5m chart for the current day if it meets following two condition:
1) The candle should be highest of the day and it's high=1234.75 (at end ".75" decimal)
2) The candle should be lowest of the day and it's low=900.25 (at end "0.25" decimal)

I could mark a candle if it's high value consist of ".75" decimal at end and low value consist of ".25" decimal behind any value using below code but it shows all candles whose high ends with "0.75". I want to mark only Day high candle if it meets 0.75 criteria. Please refer and help me out.. Thank you in advance

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at 
https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/

//@version=4
study("(75-25)", overlay=true)

ch = high[0]
cl = low[0]

truncate(number, decimals) =>
    factor = pow(10, decimals)
    int(number * factor) / factor
chA = truncate(ch,0)
chB = ch - chA
data = chB == 0.75

clA = truncate(cl,0)
clB = cl - clA
data1 = clB == 0.25


plotshape(data, style=shape.triangledown, size=size.small, location=location.abovebar, 
color=color.red)

plotshape(data1, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.small, location=location.belowbar, 
color=color.green)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `security()` function to get the daily high and lows. However, you would miss the intraday actions for backtesting. What you need I believe is, if the price is the daily high/low from the session start until that specific bar.

You can use the following method the keep track of the daily high/low and update the values if a new high/low forms.

```
var dailyHigh = high
var dailyLow = low

t = time("1440", session.regular) // Get the session open
isSessionFirstBar = na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t  // True: If first bar in the session

dailyHigh := iff(isSessionFirstBar, high, iff(high > dailyHigh, high, dailyHigh))
dailyLow := iff(isSessionFirstBar, low, iff(low < dailyLow, low, dailyLow))
```

Then you should combine this with your `data` and `data1` variables.

```
data = (chB == 0.75) and (close == dailyHigh)
data1 = (clB == 0.25) and (close == dailyLow)
```

Comment: OMG.. It works. Thank you. There's still one problem. I want to remove the previous plot in the chart if candle make a new high/low on same day. Then previous mark on the day high/low candle should be removed and marked on a newly formed candle. This continues till the day ends.

Comment: You cannot remove plots. If you would like to remove such things, you should use [drawings](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#drawings).

Comment: Okay.. Thank you so much